# OpenMP - How to effectively choose chunk sizes when scheduling

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm currently studying parallel programming and more specifically the OpenMP API. When it comes to choosing between static scheduling and dynamic scheduling, a colleague of mine told me that static is usually best when each iteration takes an equal amount of time. Otherwise dynamic is the best bet. However, there is something I don't quite understand: how does one go about choosing a suitable chunk size?

Comment: One experiments with a range of problems, problem sizes, chunk sizes, etc.  One develops an educated 'feel' for selecting an appropriate initial schedule (don't forget `guided` too) and chunk size, then one tests one's feel.

Comment: Besides schedule static and dynamic there are guided and auto which may choose a moderately large initial chunk and progressively reduce it.